# How to cancel action in c#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Note: if you click `buttonStart` and then click `buttonCancelSending` it will not raise event for `buttonCancelSending_Click` which will send signal for cancellation...
Is there anyway I can cancel foreach by clicking the buttonCancelSending?!

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Action<CancellationToken> send = async (token) =>
                {
                    await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1500));
                    int sendCount = 10;
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewReleases.Items)
                    {
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                            break;
                        if (this.Focused)
                            return;

                        if (sendCount > 0)
                        {
                            if (item.Checked == false)
                                continue;
                            SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
                            SendKeys.SendWait(Utilities.FixSenderTags(item.SubItems[1].Text));
                            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
                            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // don't send more then 10 releases
                            break;
                        }
                        sendCount--;
                    }
                    SendReleaseTypes();
                };
            send.Invoke(source.Token);
    }

    private void buttonCancelSending_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        source.Cancel(); // send the signal for cancellation!
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you already have?

Comment: token.IsCancellationRequested will always be false event if you click cancelButton

Comment: Describe in more detail what you want to happen and what happens instead. I do not understand the problem.

Comment: @usr what I want is when I click cancellation I want the app to stop/break foerach loop

Comment: @IvandroIsmael you already said that. Repeating the same information is not going to make me understand. Please describe, in detail, what is happening instead of the thing you want. Is the UI frozen? Or is just nothing happening? Place a few breakpoints to see which ones are being hit.

Answer (score 0):

I think cancel button even is not processed because the message loop is stuck in the handler for the start button due to improper usage of await/async. I believe changing

```
send.Invoke(source.token)
```

to

```
send.BeginInvoke(source.token, null)
```

should give you the desired results.

Please be aware that I have not actually compiled your code.

Comment: one more param is required

Comment: try send.BeginInvoke(source.token, null, null);

Comment: @IvandroIsmael are you saying that were incapable of adding the additional parameter? This looks like you are not trying.

Comment: @usr You got it wrong I just want to let him know that is code isn't right!

Comment: @IvandroIsmael and you expect it to be served correctly to you. I understand.